# La forme vous qui se termine par « es »

Tags: orthographe, conjugaison, histoire, linguistique

Y a-t-il des raisons historiques ou linguistiques pourquoi la forme vous de certains verbes au présent de l'indicatif se termine-t-elle par « es » ? Par exemple, êtes, dites, faites etc.

Est-ce lié à la forme vous au passé simple ? Quand la régularisation à la forme « ez » se produisit-elle ? Pourquoi ?

Comment: Trois verbes sont concernés *être*, *dire*  et *faire* (et ses dérivés). Ce sont des raisons historiques de l'évolution de la langue. Il faut du temps pour reprendre tout ça, je trouve [cette synthèse](https://septiemeartetdemi.com/2020/08/22/pourquoi-dites-et-faites-et-pas-disez-et-faisez) pas mal faite et claire.

Comment: Je ne saurais pas expliquer les raisons de l'existence de ces terminaisons, mais je pense avoir trouvé un document qui pourrait être intéressant : [Histoire et théorie de la conjugaison française](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k63403054.texteImage)

Comment: De mémoire, la deuxième personne du singulier en latin avait un "s" aussi (je n'ai pas encore lu les liens de @None et @Marck).

Comment: J'ajoute un autre lien ici, qui parle également de la 1re personne du pluriel. Pour la 2e, la phonétique (vu la forme latine) ainsi que l'utilisation très fréquente de l'impératif pour ces verbes-là, ont poussé la forme actuelle. http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/faisez.html

Answer (score 2):

it comes from the latin where the second person plural is in -tis.

The question is more why most verbs are now in -ez :-)